# Serialize a transaction

Tags: web3js

Do you know what is the purpose to serialize a transaction?

Here is an example:
const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()

Thank you

Take care

Pierre

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is used when an object needs to be represented in a string format. This is a requirement often for various transfer and storage protocols, which only understand how to use a string value but don't understand what should be done with a (custom) object.

Typically you serialize an object into for example JSON format string, transfer the string somewhere and deserialize it back into the original object format at the other end. Or for storage you may serialize the object, store the string and when needed you can retrieve the string and deserialize the original object back from the string format.

So if you want your transaction to be in string format you can serialize it.